# snappy version mismatch issue

Tags: go, homebrew, snappy

I am running some go progam on OSX but got

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libsnappy.1.dylib
Referenced from: /private/var/folders/n3/g8c23hd44v6q5f3xll_0hm80000gn/T/__TestS3Download_in_budget_test_go
Reason: Incompatible library version: ___TestS3Download_in_budget_test_go requires version 4.0.0 or later, but libsnappy.1.dylib provides version 1.0.0"
```

I've already installed snappy via homebrew.

```
$ brew info snappy
snappy: stable 1.1.7 (bottled), 
HEAD Compression/decompression library aiming for high speed  
/usr/local/Cellar/snappy/1.1.7 (18 files, 115.2KB) 
* Poured from bottle on 2017-09-09 at 20:21:48 From:  ==> Dependencies Build: cmake ✔, pkg-config ✔
```

All other packages are fine so it should only be a homebrew snappy issue

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Downgrading to snappy 1.1.4 solve the problem